# What is this 18th or 19th century muzzle gun recently used in a robbery?

Tags: weapons, identification

[image]

The spanish newspaper describes the weapon, incorrectly IMHO as a "trabuco" ([blunderbuss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blunderbuss)). I ask for a more accurate description.

https://lacronicadesalamanca.com/196620-detenido-en-aldeatejada-tras-robar-en-varios-hoteles-de-avila-a-punta-de-trabuco/

I offer a translation to the news below, but I don't know if it's appropriate. Feel free to delete that text if you want.

> The Salamanca Chronicle
>
> Arrested in Aldeatejada after robbing several hotels in Ávila at
> blunderbuss-point
>
> He took about 500 euros and ran away in a cab.
>
> The Civil Guard of Salamanca arrested this Wednesday morning at a > gas station in Aldeatejada an individual who fled after carrying > out two robberies hours earlier in hotel establishments in Avila > at blunderbuss-point.
>
> The agents believe that he could also be the author of a third > > robbery
> committed in another hotel in the capital of Avila on Wednesday night.
> At the National Police Station in Ávila on Wednesday was received the
> notice from several hotels alerting of having been victims of
> robberies by a man who carried an old muzzle gun, which led to an
> investigation that allowed the identification of the criminal.
> Meanwhile, the alleged robber, who had fled by taxi, stopped at first
> to refuel at a gas station in the province of Avila, where he required
> the employee to exchange coins for bills, at which time the worker
> realized that the man had a gun, something he reported to the Guardia Civil
>
> After these communications, the police officers began working together
> to determine that the individual who had exchanged money at the gas
> station was the same one who had previously docked at the hotel
> establishments.
>
> After being intercepted at the second stop at a petrol station, this
> time in Aldeatejada, the agents checked that the suspect was the same,
> and when they searched him they found the pistol and nearly 500 euros
> in banknotes and coins, which led to his arrest.
>
> On the other hand, the Avila Police are investigating whether the
> detainee is also the author of another robbery of a hotel in the city
> that was committed on Wednesday afternoon. If this fact is confirmed,
> there would be three hotels in the capital of Avila that suffered the
> same type of crime.

Comment: It's just a pistol.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't look like a ["trabuco"](https://decoracion-nautica.com/replicas-de-trabucos/1208-replica-de-trabuco.html). Those tend to have a trumpet like ending, and use a [flintlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flintlock).

It looks more like a short barreled [percussion cap pistol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percussion_cap). (No idea of the maker though.)

[image: Percussion cap pistol, early 19th]

[image: Percussion cap pistol]

Comment: Could be a conversion from an older flint lock to cap lock. Also, possibly, the barrel is a cut down from an old rifle. Maybe lock, stock and barrel all started life separately.